# Numpy Indexing problem..... Advance indexing what is X[0] doing here?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, python-3.7, numpy-indexing

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]])

y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])

counts = {}

print(X[y == 0])

# prints = [[0 1 0 1]
# [0 0 0 1]]
```

I want to know why `X[y==0]` printing two data point. Shouldn't it print only `[0 1 0 1]` ?

because `X[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y == 0` gives an array with same dimensions as `y`, with elements `True` where the corresponding element in `y` is `0`, and `False` otherwise.

Here, `y` has `0` elements at indices `0` and `2`. So, `X[y == 0]` gives you an array containing `X[0]` and `X[2]`.